# execute route change from siblings component in React Router V4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am learning React.js. I am using React router version 4.3.1 and React router dom 4.3.1.

My current app structure is given below.

```
<React.Fragment>
  {/* sidebar component */}
  <SideBar store = {Mystore} />
  <div className="main-panel">
  {/* navbar component */}
  <NavBar store = {Mystore}/>
  {/* content component */}
  <Content store = {Mystore}/>
  {/* footer component */}
  </div>
</React.Fragment>
```

in my content component i have a Router set up as given below.

```
<BrowserRouter> 
  <React.Fragment> 
  <Route exact path="/phoenix/public" component={Login} /> 
  <ProtectedRoute exact path="/phoenix/public/sample" component={SamplePage} /> 
  <ProtectedRoute exact path="/phoenix/public/view_ticket" component={ViewTicket} /> 
  <ProtectedRoute exact path="/phoenix/public/create_ticket" component={CreateTicket} /> 
  <ProtectedRoute exact path="/phoenix/public/dashboard" component={Dashborad} /> 
  </React.Fragment> 
</BrowserRouter>
```

Here **ProtectedRoute** is a functional component which checks if the user is authenticated and returns a  **Route**

My sidebar has some **a** tags like below.

```
<li> 
  <a href="dashboard"> 
  <i className="ti-panel" /> 
  <p>Dashboard</p> 
  </a> 
</li>
```

**My goal is to navigate to different Routes without page refresh on click from side bar.** But clicking href reloads the page and all my state in my Mobx refreshes. I have tried to **Redirect** but could not get the Router which is stated in siblings component (content is siblings of sidebar). I have no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried using [Link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link)?

Comment: Have you tried navigationOption props?

Comment: I have tried to use links but i guess it needs a Router but my sidebar component does not have a Router. How can i use link in sidebar component if my Router is set up in content ?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments on your question, regular `<a>` tags will not work, and refresh the page. So you will need to use [Link](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link) or NavLink.

If you want to make it work in your sidebar (child component) you will need to wrap the `<BrowserRouter>` around all the components where you want to use the routes.

For example like this (using your code):

```
<BrowserRouter>
<React.Fragment>
  {/* sidebar component */}
  <SideBar store = {Mystore} />
  <div className="main-panel">
  {/* navbar component */}
  <NavBar store = {Mystore}/>
  {/* content component */}
  <Content store = {Mystore}/>
  {/* footer component */}
  </div>
</React.Fragment>
</BrowserRouter>
```

And your Sidebar will be something like this:

```
<React.Fragment>
    <Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link> 
    ...
</React.Fragment>
```

Then in your content component. You need to delete the `<BrowserRouter>`

Comment: i am successful in navigating to the desired route with your solution but the content does not change to according route

Comment: Do you have a switch around your routes?
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Switch

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by having BrowserRouter like below as suggested by @PreDinnerSnack.

```
<BrowserRouter>
<React.Fragment>
  {/* sidebar component */}
  <SideBar store = {Mystore} />
  <div className="main-panel">
  {/* navbar component */}
  <NavBar store = {Mystore}/>
  {/* content component */}
  <Content store = {Mystore}/>
  {/* footer component */}
  </div>
</React.Fragment>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Then i used Navlink in My Sidebar component. Which fixed the problem of navigating to the desired route without page refresh. But then i faced another problem as Content was not Refreshing according to the route.

For that problem I found the observer HOC of Mobx was interfering with my router. I had to wrap my content with withRouter as below to fix this problem.

```
withRouter(observer(Content));
```

I hope my solution will come in handy for someone as i found no tutorial with the examples of React Router implementation like mine on the web.